# Not able to run scripts on Azure ADO pipeline getting failed to create driver exception on local it is working fine, issue on pipeline only

Tags: java, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, playwright, playwright-java

I am getting this below exception when I run pipeline on azure ado and automation tool is playwright

```
> Task :testJsonConfig
[gradle]: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create driver
[gradle]:   at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.driver.Driver.createAndInstall(Driver.java:105)
[gradle]:   at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.driver.Driver.ensureDriverInstalled(Driver.java:57)
[gradle]:   at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.PlaywrightImpl.createImpl(PlaywrightImpl.java:45)
[gradle]:   at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.PlaywrightImpl.create(PlaywrightImpl.java:35)
[gradle]:   at com.microsoft.playwright.Playwright.create(Playwright.java:110)
[gradle]:   at com.microsoft.playwright.Playwright.create(Playwright.java:114)
[gradle]:   at Regression_Suite.SmokeCheckAllOem$BrowserTest.run(SmokeCheckAllOem.java:74)
[gradle]:   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
```

On my local machine, everything is working perfectly fine, I do not know what is the issue with azure ADO pipeline. I tried to generate lib folder to keep all jar that we can use for pipeline execution, that didn't help either

Is it related to the azure machine that we have or any library that I need to provide to create the browser instances?

It also gives error that GLIBC 2.27 version not found required by Playwright

Comment: Azure ADO? you mean Azure DevOps???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please edit the post to contain a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It will help the community experts understand your workflow/scenario/ reproducing steps. Please also share the [pipeline definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/migrate/from-classic-pipelines?view=azure-devops#export-your-classic-pipeline) and [debug logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops) of the affected pipeline in the post.

Comment: The information you provided is too limited for us to understand how you run what script to create driver on `azure machine`(MS-hosted agent you mean?)

Comment: Yes i am using azure devops to run my pipeline ,  my test case is working locally fine but when i run on azure devops it is not working , it is not able to initialize browser on azure , giving this exception along with GLIBC 2.27 version not found error also coming

Comment: The information you provided is fairly limited. We cannot tell what is wrong with your workflow based on your narratives. Please check my shared links and provide a minimal reproducible example of you project/script, you pipeline definition and debug logs. We can continue troubleshooting accordingly.